# File size of 1 million rand numbers

Tags: compression

The file by rand is 1 million random numbers. It is compressed down to 415 kb....how is this possible if it is impossible to compress random data.

Thank you.

Jon Hutton

Comment: Do you have some more details, from what you've written it could still describe a situation where a file with comma-separated decimal numbers is compressed (obviously trivial).

Comment: Actually, if you had a file filled with random decimal numbers, the expected compression ratio is *really close* to your observation.. that's kind of suspicious

Comment: Thank you for your answer Harold. It made no sense to me how a word pad document with a million random digits could compress using winrar down to 415, 241 kb. Original file size 1.37mb. I am not a programmer but have basic binary and compression understanding.

Comment: The fundamental problem with that is that it's not random at the representation in which it is stored, which is of course bytes. Storing one decimal digit per byte, even if the digits are random, is compressible by a factor of about 2.4 because only 10 out of the 256 possible values are used. But just re-coding it to a more suitable representation does the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

You're most likely talking about the famous ["A Million Random Digits"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Million_Random_Digits_with_100,000_Normal_Deviates) test data that was published in 1955. So it's digits, not numbers, as Mark already guessed, that's why the binary version is only 415,241 bytes. Also see [Mark Nelson's homepage](http://marknelson.us/2006/06/20/million-digit-challenge/) that has a link to [the binary file](http://marknelson.us/attachments/million-digit-challenge/AMillionRandomDigits.bin).

Note that the end result (the binary file) is not compressible without knowing it - although there are some small redundancies in the file that come from the way it was created - see [this forum entry](https://encode.su/threads/1768-Competition-on-compression-(-)?p=34203&viewfull=1#post34203) for more details:

> There are potentially other biases in the million random digits file
> that I discussed years ago in comp.compression. The data was
> originally generated by sampling a 5 bit counter driven by a noisy
> oscillator to produce a set of 20,000 punched cards with 50 digits
> each. But there was some correlation between consecutive digits, so
> what they did was add adjacent pairs of cards modulo 10 to produce a
> new set of cards which was published. That is why the sums of the
> columns are even. Each of the original cards is counted twice.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like they're stored as one decimal digit per byte. So using only ten of the 256 possible bytes values leaves you with the potential for a log(256)/log(10) compression ratio on random digits, which is about 2.4. You're getting 2.35 (assuming "kb" = 1024 bytes). Voila.

You can get 2.4 quite easily by coding every three digits into ten bits, since 1024 > 1000. Then you can code 1,000,000 decimal digits into 416,667 bytes, or 406.9 KiB.

With a little more difficulty, using something like [GMP](https://gmplib.org/), you could code it as a giant million-digit integer in binary, which would take 415,242 bytes, or 405.5 KiB. That would be as good as it gets for random decimal digits.

Comment: Good reply, easy to understand for this non programmer. Perhaps on average you could code 3 digits with 10 bits. Zeroes would really be difficult. It looks more like what you mentioned in your second idea with GMP.

Comment: Not understanding your comment. Zeros are difficult? You can code 3 decimal digits into 10 bits period. Not just on average. Every time.

Comment: First thanks, for not ridiculing my ignorance. I was not sure how three zeroes could be coded differently than two zeroes and a 9 using 10 bits 0000001001. 999 can be represented easily enough by 1111100111. Zero zero one had me puzzled.

Comment: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1e/Viola_d%27amore.jpg

Comment: @pericynthion Thanks. Fixed the spelling. :-)

Comment: @jonhutton You can code any three digits into 10 bits with a very simple scheme - just group the three digits into an integer in the range 0-999, and translate it directly into binary.  24 codes are unused.  It sounds like you were also wanting to be able to encode 0, 1 or 2 digits into the same space, i.e. distinguishing "000" from "0", or "012" from "12" - that won't fit.

Comment: You can encode a single digit in the leftover 10-bit patterns, as well as a single digit marking end of stream, and simply end of stream. (With three patterns still leftover.) Then for a self-terminating stream of an arbitrary number of digits, you will need at most 20 bits for the last 0, 1, or 2 digits.

Comment: "You can code any three digits into 10 bits with a very simple scheme - just group the three digits into an integer in the range 0-999. "Once again thanks for simple explanations... i was thinking since we are dealing with an rng the output will not be guaranteed to be 0-999, but 0,0,0, to 9,9,9 complicating slightly the overall numver of bits required